# I can't get my footer to be full width

Tags: css, html

I can't get my footer full width. It follows the parrent div which is 70 %. 
I don't know how to change it to be full width cause when i move it down to get its own container, it will end up in the header or lay over the previous content. 
Can anyone help me??
please! thaanks

```css
/* FOOTER */
footer {
    margin-top: 40px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(226, 219, 219, 0.94); 
}
.footer_col1 {
    height: 70px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
.footer_col2 {
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
Here is some of my Html:
<div class="colonne_1_left_section4">
            <h1 style="padding-top: 90px;">COMBINE DESIGN &amp; COLORS</h1>
            <p class="trolley_text">The Art Trolley size 42 x 40.5 centimeters can be combined with our wall mount (Bamboo combined light/dark &amp; light or dark)- and hanged on it.<br><br>
            Choice of color completely up to you:<br><br>
        <img class="trolley_color_icons" alt="trolley color icons"src="billeder/colors_icon.png" style="float: left;">
        </p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="colonne_2_right_section4">
        <img class="trolley1" alt="trolley visual by groos"src="billeder/1.jpg">
        </div><br><br>
        
        
    <footer>
  <div class="footer_col1">
    <a href="#">
      <img alt="instagram_icon" src="billeder/Instagram_icon.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; padding-right: 10px;"></a>
    <a href="#">
      <img alt="facebppl_icon" src="billeder/facebook_icon.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; padding-left: 10px;"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="footer_col2">VISUAL ART BY GROOS © 2018</div>
        <div class="footer_col3">+45 27 50 12 83     info.visualbygroos@gmail.com</div>
</footer> 
        
</div>  
</div>

<script src="hamburger.js"></script>
<script src="slideshow"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your css looks good to me, I think not the footer is the problem

Comment: Are the last two closing ˋDIVˋ tages needed? I can‘t see the coresponding opening ˋDIVˋ tags for them. Please check your ˋHTMLˋ once again

Comment: the last two DIV' tags is a part of a bigger code. 
I still can't get my footer right?

Comment: @MarieEgeberg Can you please select an answer as the accepted answer? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

every time you use the HTML make sure that your body tag has margin 0

```
body {
        margin: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using vw (viewport width) units instead of all that % stuff. Using vw allows you to define a size regardless of the imbrication of the div you are working on within other divs but according to the size of your window screen:

```
footer {
    width: 100vw;
}
```

Since 1vw is 1/100 of your screen width, width: 100vw means: "Make this div span the entire screen width".

Comment: thanks it is full width now but it floats to the right so you need to scroll on on page, what can I do about that?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your `body` and `html` always have `margin: 0;`, otherwise you end up with extra space like with your footer. Like this you can use a width of 100% and won't experience any problems :)

```
body, html {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
}

/* FOOTER */
footer {
    margin-top: 40px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(226, 219, 219, 0.94); 
}
.footer_col1 {
    height: 70px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}
.footer_col2 {
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="colonne_1_left_section4">
  <h1 style="padding-top: 90px;">COMBINE DESIGN &amp; COLORS</h1>
  <p class="trolley_text">The Art Trolley size 42 x 40.5 centimeters can be combined with our wall mount (Bamboo combined light/dark &amp; light or dark)- and hanged on it.<br><br> Choice of color completely up to you:<br><br>
    <img class="trolley_color_icons" alt="trolley color icons" src="billeder/colors_icon.png" style="float: left;">
  </p>
</div>

<div class="colonne_2_right_section4">
  <img class="trolley1" alt="trolley visual by groos" src="billeder/1.jpg">
</div><br><br>


<footer>
  <div class="footer_col1">
    <a href="#">
      <img alt="instagram_icon" src="billeder/Instagram_icon.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; padding-right: 10px;"></a>
    <a href="#">
      <img alt="facebppl_icon" src="billeder/facebook_icon.png" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; padding-left: 10px;"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="footer_col2">VISUAL ART BY GROOS © 2018</div>
  <div class="footer_col3">+45 27 50 12 83 info.visualbygroos@gmail.com</div>
</footer>
```